# How do spell attacks work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

How do spell attacks work?

Roll 1D20 + your spell Attack Modifier.

Spell Attack modifier = 2 + 2 (Charisma Modifier) For a total of 4.

I roll a D20 and get 10. Add 4, to get a total of 14. What I am attacking say has an AC of 14. It hits.

My question is: is this interpretation of how spell attacks work correct?

Spell attacks are roll D20 + Add Spell Attack modifier.

Trying to understand how spell attacks work.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour], and check out the [help] for more guidance. First of all, what RPG and edition are you playing? D&D 5e, or something else? You can edit the tag (e.g. [dnd-5e]) into your post to clarify this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game & edition you're asking about?

Comment: @ViperIsOP Don't be disheartened if your question is closed as a duplicate! That doesn't mean it's a bad question, just that the question has already been asked (and likely answered) elsewhere on this stack exchange!